# Installing Moto X 2nd Gen Debug Driver

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, android

I have a **Windows 7 x64 Ultimate** computer and I want to connect my **Moto X 2nd Gen (XT1097)** in debug mode so I can develop some apps.

The problem is, Windows can't find the drivers for my Moto X. I have downloaded [Motorola Device Manager](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/88481) (version 2.4.5) which is supposed to have all the drivers but still my Windows can't find the driver. And before anyone asks, yes, I do have debug enabled in the settings of my phone.

So here comes the funny part..... I have tried this same thing with another Win7x64 Ultimate real machine and a Virtual Machine (running inside my own PC). At first Windows couldn't install the debug drivers...but then after I download the **Motorola Device Manager** it installed the debug drivers and I was able to use the phone for development.

The weird thing is, when I connect my phone into my PC, it installs all the media drivers but not the debug ones and this is how my phone is listed under my Window's **Device Manager**:

[image: XT1097 device]

**BUT** in all the other two computers (in which the drivers were successfully installed), this is how my phone is listed, before I install the Motorola Device Manager (which contains all the drivers):

[image: ADB Interface device]

And this is how it's listed after the driver's installation:

[image]

So, in order to try to fix this, I tried to force a driver installation. I found the driver myself under "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Motorola Shared\Mobile Drivers\Drivers" and inside `motoandroid2.inf` I could find a driver called "Motorola ADB Interface" and even my phone's VID/PID was inside this same driver's file!......**BUT it didn't work!**

I still can't use this phone in debug mode, I can't make Android studio see when it's connected, and I also tried to change Google's default driver `android_winusb.inf` including my phone in there, [using this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709263/google-android-usb-driver-and-adb), but again nothing happens.

Does anyone has any clues of what is going on? I am lost, and honestly I don't want to format my PC just because of this.

Answer (score 0):

I just went through the exact same thing, and I think I've got the solution.  When I first connected it, it connected as a media device, and I thought "That's not what I want, lets disable that"...so I went ahead and unchecked the "Connect as media device" option, and enabled debug via usb....then after a few frustrating reboots and tests, I forgot to uncheck the media device option first...and all of a sudden I got a different sound.  (when it was failing, the normal usb device connected sound from windows "da-daa-da" was replaced with more of an error-ish "wah-wah"...but this time it was the normal)  So I checked device manager and it was installing properly and TaDa! It installed the ADB drivers.
So in short....keep media device checked, and try that.